# Wrap a list of WebElements and present as a single WebElement

Tags: htmlelements

I am automating testing of a response web app and have an issue with multiple elements on the page with the same @FindBy selector where only one is visible at a particular screen resolution (in this case a logout button that 'moves' around the screen).

I could just get a list of webelements and click on the first visible, but I was wondering if I could do something smarter using html elements:

**Given** the following annotation

```
@FindBy(css = ".logoutButton")
MultiWebElement logoutButton;
```

**When** I call this method

```
logoutButton.click();
```

**Then** the MultiWebElement class will iterate over all elements that match the find by and call the click method on the first one that isDisplayed().

Unfortunately the decorator seems to want logoutButton to be of type List which defeats the purpose of creating the new class.

Can I do something like this, or is this outside the current scope?

Comment: can you show `MultiWebElement` implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code any more, I got frustrated with it and thew it away :-)  I'd just copied the button class and played around.  I'm thinking that I could probably override some method, grab the findby annotation and do the search myself.

Comment: The more I look into the less likely I think that it will work.  I believe I need to implement a custom locator and I don't think htmlelements allows for that.

Comment: i can't see any problem in your approach, everything should work as you expect. try to define your `logoutButton` as `WebElement` at first.